# Why the fields are not being displayed in the disign interface when I drag and drop from the pallet?

Tags: android-studio, drag-and-drop

I am a newbie, just started working with android studio.
I have created just a blank activity in which hello world text field is displayed, when I try to drag and drop Button/TextView or any other elements it's not being displayed on the screen and the screen remains gray in Design interface, but in Text interface fields were added.
Why the fields are not being displayed in the design interface when I drag and drop it from the pallet?

Comment: add some codes you have used and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync your project with gradle files from the icon next to AVD Manager.